# PHP - Sort textarea submission to two separate arrays (numbers and letters)

Tags: php, arrays

I am quite new to php and am challenging myself everyday. My question may be simple, and I may be thinking to hard. But I have a textarea, that accepts values and then adds them to an array. What I am trying to do is sort the submitted values so that numbers go into one array and letters go into a separate array. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

This is what I have so far:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="GET">
<p>Please enter your numbers</p>
<textarea name='numbers'>
</textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<?php
 $numbers= $_GET['numbers'];
 if(isset($_GET['numbers'])){
 if (!strlen(trim($_GET['numbers']))){
print "enter unlimited numbers on seperate lines";
  }else{
print_r(explode("\n",$numbers));
}
 }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The numbers and letters are on separate lines?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I suppose, I just want to sort the submitted values. My overall goal is to grab the submitted info from the text area and create a file that sorts the input. So like Values: 1 2 3 4 a b 6 7 c Total numbers = 7 Total even = 3 Total odd = 3 Invalid numbers = a b c

Answer (score 0):

Assuming array values are on separate lines:

```
if(!empty($_GET['numbers'])){
    $lines = explode("\n", $_GET['numbers']);
    $numbers = array_filter('is_numeric', $lines);
    $others  = array_diff($lines, $numbers);
} else {
    print "enter unlimited numbers on separate lines";
}
```

Comment: I am getting a error from using that Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/comp1230/prelabs/pl4/index.php on line 20

Warning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #2 is not an array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/comp1230/prelabs/pl4/index.php on line 21